# Looking for pin-out for 4 pin analogue CD-ROM audio cable

Tags: audio, optical-drive, compact-disc

Remember those 4-pin audio cables which went from optical disk drive to sound card? I'm looking for pin-out for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, Ground, Ground, Left. Left-to-right on the drive, reverse for on the sound card.

Comment: That's left to right when looking at the connectors on the drive, right?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.epanorama.net/documents/pc/cdrom_audio_wire.html

Comment: I actually fount that site on my own, but it didn't enlighten me enough. I still can't find which is pin one on the cable.